# react-router-redux vs connected-react-router for react v4

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

[official](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) github page of `react-router-redux` says that the project is no longer maintained and is now deprecated. They recommend to use `connected-react-router` instead.
`react-router-redux` has:
31k stars
884 watch
6k forks
while `connected-react-router` has only:
1053 stars
28 watch
108 forks

I am starting developing a complete Q/A social networking website using react v4, will it be worthy or smart idea to use `connected-react-router` here?

while posting the question I just noticed that the stackoverflow doesn't even have `connected-react-router` tag.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. Have you got any answer from someone yet? Best regards

Comment: Nope. I wonder if people are using `connected-react-router`. If you see their github issue profile, there are a lot of open issues and some of them don't have any activity done so far.

Answer (score 7):

If you are going to use Redux to manage your application state, use react router for routing, and want to synchronize your route history with your app state and manage routing through redux, then this will be fine to use. While I've only begun using it recently myself it's made been pretty straight forward for managing routing, including route data.

You also pointed out that:

> `react-router-redux` says that the project is no longer maintained

For this reason alone I would not use `react-router-redux`, unless you plan to maintain it yourself. Disregarding features and bugs, you'd also have to be concerned with any potential security issues that come up. Please also see this dicussion they're having about it's deprecation in their GitHub issues https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6358

Just to reiterate, if you need, or think you'll need, to synchronize your router state with your redux store then this is not a bad tool to use. If you don't think you'll need this then don't use it so your project doesn't become bloated.

That being said, I've also seen this alternative https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history which looks interesting. It looks to offer a more decoupled approach to history, routing, and state than the `connected-react-router`, but I haven't used it yet.